# Need VBA code to plot up series of linear data in Excel, create regression eq's for each series, then write the regression eq's in the Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly simple VBA code which is doing 75% of what I need it to do, I just can't get the last step to work properly.

In an Excel sheet, I have two sets of data (X data and Y data).  The x data is the same two data values for every single case.  Then I have two columns of data which comprise the Y data.  I need to create an Excel scatter plot with a whole bunch of data series.  Series 1 is the two constant x values with the first y value from the first column and the first y value from the second column.  The 2nd series is the same two constant x values with the second y value from the first column and the second y value from the second column, and so on.  The columns have about 300+ rows (hence > 300 series total).  I realize that a scatter plot can only do up to about 256 series in one plot so I won't be able to fit them all in one plot.  That's not the point.  I've tried just plotting like, say, 50 of the series and I have that part working fine.  Next, because all the series are straight lines, I need the slope/regression information from each series, so I create a linear trendline and plot the equation on the chart.  I have this part automated and working correctly in Excel as well.  Here's where I'm stuck though.  The last step is, after I've had VBA create the, say, 50 series in the single plot and generate all of the regression equations, I then need for Excel to take those equations and paste them into a column in the main worksheet (where the plotting data resides).  I found something on Google that is supposed to do this (grabbing trendline.datalabel.text and pasting it into the sheet), but it isn't working right, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried 20 different things and am still beating my head against a wall.  Any help with the last half of the code would be greatly appreciated.  THANK YOU.

```
Sub Plot_slopes()


Dim i As Integer

Dim ChtOb As ChartObject


   Dim objTrendline As Trendline

  Dim strEquation As String


Set ChtOb = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=20, Width:=800, Top:=20, Height:=250)

ChtOb.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ChtOb.Activate


i = 9


For i = 9 To 59



With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "FS" & i
    .XValues = Worksheets("summary").Range(Worksheets("summary").Cells(3, 7), Worksheets("summary").Cells(4, 7))
    .Values = Worksheets("summary").Range(Worksheets("summary").Cells(i, 13), Worksheets("summary").Cells(i, 14))
    .Trendlines.Add


     End With



With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

Set objTrendline = .Trendlines(1)

With objTrendline

   .DisplayRSquared = False
    Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True
    strEquation = .DataLabel.Text
    Range("Q9").Offset(i, 0) = strEquation


End With

End With



    Next i




End Sub
```

I mainly need help with the code after the first With Block and where it starts with a new "with"..."with activesheet.chartobjects(1).chart", etc), although, I'm also having trouble with the .name part in the first With block as well.  Goal is to get the last block so that VBA writes out the regression equations for each created series into the main "summary" worksheet

Comment: You don't have to pick the regression out of the plot - you can do it directly with formulas - eg. http://science.clemson.edu/physics/labs/tutorials/excel/regression.html

Comment: Thanks - that's actually a great point - I didn't realize you could do it with formulas.  I could bypass VBA altogether with that method.  Thanks!